# Strange Behaviour of an Array in a run-length code decoding

Tags: c, arrays, run-length-encoding

((link to original question incase you know german : https://stepik.org/lesson/193516/step/9?unit=167933)

Task : printf("falsche eingabe") whenever there's something false in the input, if everything is correct then just print the decoded version. There are also 2 modes ( single (abc) / multi (aaa) )  and whenever there's a change in modes you also need to print " ' " (the starting mode is single mode.)

Sample Input 1:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl

Sample Output 1:

falsche eingabe

Sample Input 2:

abcdefg

Sample Output 2:

abcdefg

Sample Input 3:

'a2b3c2d2'efg

Sample Output 3:

aabbbccddefg

Hi. This is a homework of mine and I already managed to do it the long way, by just decoding the input and thinking of every condition in which the original input is wrong. Then I thought well.. This shouldn't be the best way of doing it. Therefore I decided to decode the code and encode it back again, and if the saved input matches with my encoded version, just print the decoded data, Otherwise, error.
The problem is that whenever I try the inputs 
1- 'a2
2- ax

The decoding doesnt work right. I get results like
1- aa* || aaİ || aa? || ..... ( aa + a random mark )
2- ax + a random sign

When I try inputs with same logic but longer length, the programm works just fine.

I'd be glad if someone knows and shows a way of fixing the decoding. I also don't want to solve this problem just by adding a for-loop in the end if possible..

Thank you already

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char el[50];
    scanf("%s", &el); // 'a2b2c3'dfh
    char saved[50]; // 'a2b2c3'dfh
    char decoded[50]; //aabbcccdfh

    int k, h, y = -1, b = -1; //

    int multi = 0; //(while decoding) 1 -> multi , 0 -> not
    char encoded[50]; // 'a2b2c3'dfh
    int multi2 = 0; //(while encoding)

    for (k = 0; el[k] != '\0'; k++) { //saving

        saved[k] = el[k]; // 'a2b2c3'dfh
    }

    for (k = 0; el[k] != '\0'; k++) { //decoding

        if (el[k] == 39) {
            continue;
        }

        if (50 <= el[k + 1] && el[k + 1] <= 57) { // 2->9
            if (multi == 0)
                multi = 1;
        }

        if (multi == 0) {
            y++;
            decoded[y] = el[k];
        }

        else { //multi ==1 //a2
            for (h = 0; h < (int)el[k + 1] - 48; h++) {

                y++;
                decoded[y] = el[k];
                multi = 0;
            }

            k++;
        }

    } // decoded = aabbcccdfh ( hier ist k = laenge )

    if (k > 30) {
        printf("falsche eingabe");
        return 0;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < y + 1; k++) {
        if (decoded[k] == decoded[k + 1]) {

            if (multi2 == 0) {
                multi2 = 1;
                b++;
                encoded[b] = 39;
            }
        }

        if (multi2 == 0) {
            b++;
            encoded[b] = decoded[k];
        }
        else {
            b++;
            encoded[b] = decoded[k];
            // 0 -> decoded[k], 1 -> for, 2-> '

            for (h = k; decoded[h] == decoded[h + 1]; h++)
                ;

            b++;
            encoded[b] = ((h - k + 48) + 1);

            k = h;

            if (decoded[k + 1] != decoded[k + 2]) {
                multi2 = 0;
                b++;
                encoded[b] = 39;
            }
        }
    }

    //wurde die erste eingabe richtig codiert ? ( also gibt es fehler oder nicht ? )

    for (k = 0; saved[k] != '\0'; k++) {
        if (saved[k] != encoded[k]) {
            printf("falsche eingabe\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", decoded);
}
```

I tried to make it as clear as possible, I'm sorry if it could've been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The specification says:

- it starts in single modus
- when a `'` is seen, it switches between modes
- in multi-modus a letter (Zeichen) is followed by a digit (Ziffer, so a *single* digit), that says how often the letter (Zeichen) must be repeated. (So the max repeat is 9.)

Just simply implement this as specified and you are done.

Example:

```
abc'd2e4'ma'r2 --> abcddeeeemarr
```

Comment: Your example should result in "falsche eingabe" because the character `'` is missing between `4` and `ma`; the compressed string has to be: `abc'd2e4'ma'r2` in German language it describes that the `'` always switches between both modes.

Comment: @TomKuschel, the spec says "_so wird nur einmal in den Multimodus umgeschalten und erst beim nächsten "Einzelgänger" zurückgeschalten_", so the transition from multi to single is implicit because no digit follows `m`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie TomKuschel is right. Your given entry should result in "falsche eingabe" .  There's a ' whenever the mode changes... "Der Übergang zwischen Single- und Multimodus wird durch das Trennzeichen ' (einfaches Hochkomma) markiert."

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie, you are right with _"Einzelgänger zurückschalten"_, but there is no definition about _"Einzelgänger"_ in detail, you didn't read past the following _" Der Übergang zwischen Single- und Multimodus wird durch das Trennzeichen ' (einfaches Hochkomma) markiert."_ - this means both directions of transformation and also the example with: **'a2b3c2d2'efg** does clearly define the behavior.

Comment: By the way, the German text with _wird ... zurückgeschalten_ is grammatically wrong, should be _wird ... zurückgeschaltet_. ;-)

Comment: @TomKuschel, OK, I agree. The keyword is _zwischen_ (between).

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems

1) you're calling `scanf` incorrectly

```
scanf("%s",&el);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s",el);
```

because you're passing it a string

2) you don't NUL terminate your strings. This can lead to undefined behaviour as the code won't know where the string ends and will quite happily overrun your arrays.

Add the terminating character after your loops like below. Once the loop has finished `k` will point to the last value.

```
for (k = 0; el[k] != '\0'; k++) { //saving

    saved[k] = el[k]; // 'a2b2c3'dfh
}
saved[k] = '\0';
```

Also another issue I've just spotted is you're populating strings like `decoded` in an odd way that makes it hard to NUL terminate them.

The `y++` should go after you store the value into the array like below (and obviously you should initialise it with `0` not `-1`).

```
        decoded[y] = el[k];
        y++;
```

This means that when you've done populating `decoded` you can do `decoded[y]='\0'` to terminate it as `y` will be pointing at the end just like `k` does with the `saved` loop above.

Same goes for `encode` and `b`

Comment: For this very code, the lack of & operand doesn't change anything. I used to scan strings in the way you mentioned, but faced some problems and then decided to go this way again..

Comment: Taking out the & should stop you getting warnings about passing the wrong type of thing to `scanf`

Comment: as far as I know c puts in a "\0" at the end of an array while scanning input for it. The problematic part of the code is the for-loop used for decoding, and there the string used was scanned. So that also shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: yes - `scanf` will NUL terminate `el`, but it won't terminate `saved`, `decoded` or `encoded` - you need to do that yourself

Comment: well then what would have been the most efficient way of doing it ?  I tried to do like decoded[k+1] = '\0' for the last value of k but naturally it didn't help. I think to do it right I should determine the length of the decoded version first. And that seems like long work...

Comment: you want `decoded[k]='\0'` as when the loop finishes `k` will point to the last value

Comment: I tried that too. The input 'a2 still gives aa + one random character. I also tried to write the estimated change in variables on paper and tracked them all. I found the correct answers on paper but c doesn't function as I wish it does.....

Comment: Ah, actually I just noticed you're indexing using `y` for `decoded`, but you're incrementing it incorrectly, so that won't work - I'll update my answer with more details